# How to call Python script from Android

Tags: android, python

Is it possible in Android to call Python script? I have already some scripts in Python 2.7 and I want to call that from Android(that script create file and fills with data). To be more specific I am trying to execute Python script on phone, that script connects to some site, download data and do some intelligence and then create file with new data(json on phone).

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you trying to execute a Python script on your Android device? Or is the script located somewhere else?

Comment: Check out android-scripting: http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/

Comment: @Lukas Knuth I am trying to execute on phone Python script

Answer (score 5):

With googles [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)-project, it's possible to have Python-scripts execute on your Android phone.

Parts of the Android API are wrapped for Python (but not all of it)

You can [embed Python-scripts in your application](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/FAQ#Can_I_use_SL4A_to_write_a_real_Android_application_or_embed_SL4A) (sounds like your approach).